# SonarQube analysis of C# file failing: References to a line number not present in the file

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

While running sonarqube analysis through GitLab's CI system, an interesting failure occurs at the very end of the SonarQube scan process:

[image]

The Gitlab slave machine, where this process takes place, has the following configuration:

- OS: Windows Server 12 R2 (64 bit)
- Sonar scanner for MSBuild version:3.0.1.635
- MSBuild version : 15 (with Visual Studio 2017)
- SonarC# version : 6.1.0.2359

The version of SonarQube server used is 6.4

It seems that the Sonar scanner is still referring to on older version of the file, which had more number of lines than the newer version. Earlier, I'd resolved this issue by deleting the cache built up in Gitlab runner, but this time, removing the cache has had no effect. Googling this error hasn't let me anywhere (or perhaps my Google Fu is weak). And this seems to be an issue with only this particular project, as the SonarQube analysis of the rest of the dotnet core projects is running fine on the same system.

Any pointers/help/explanation would be appreciated.

Edit: This problem was caused by the encoding of the file (UTF-8 with BOM). Upon changing the encoding to UTF-8, the error disappeared. Many thanks to Valeri from SonarSource team for [pointing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100182/sonarqube-analysis-of-c-sharp-file-failing-references-to-a-line-number-not-pres?noredirect=1#comment81152423_47100182) it out

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarC# installed on your SonarQube instance (Administration > System > Update Center)

Comment: This usually happens when the encoding of one of the files in your project is "unexpected". The latest versions of SonarC# should print the file name in the log. It would be best if you use UTF8 no BOM encoding.

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam: This worked. The file had UTF-8 with BOM encoding, and after changing it to UTF-8, the error disappeared.Thanks a lot!
Is this included in the official documentation somewhere? Or can you answer this question here, so that I can mark this as the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the encoding of one or more of the files in your project is "unexpected" to SonarQube. The latest versions of SonarC# will print the name of the file that is breaking the analysis and you could save it with different encoding, usually UTF8 without BOM works the best.

This problem is relatively rare, but I think you are right and it deserves a place in our documentation. I will create a page and will update the answer with the link.